# SQL 2 counts with different filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I need calculate two aggregate functions with different conditions in one statement. How can I do this?

Pseudocode below:

```
SELECT count(CoumntA) *< 0*, count(CoumntA) * > 0*
FROM dbo.TableA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same idea as tombom's answer, but with SQL Server syntax:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN CoumntA < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LessThanZero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CoumntA > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GreaterThanZero
FROM TableA
```

Comment: Why was this marked as the answer, when I wrote practically the same thing about three minutes before?

Comment: Sorry @Dommer, didn't see your answer when I posted it. Personally, I think Dems answer is the most complete.

Comment: That's cool. I think mine feels faster as I deliberately don't bother with the `CASE ELSE` bit, but I bet they are all the same really.

Comment: @Dommer - Without an an explicit else block you implicitly have `ELSE NULL`.  So the only real beneift would be initially parsing the query string, but the plan would be identical.

Answer (score 4):

As @tombom demonstrated, this ***can*** be done as a single query.  But it doesn't mean that it *should* be.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN CoumntA < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS less_than_zero,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CoumntA > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS greater_than_zero
FROM
  TableA
```

The time when this is not so good is...
- There is an index on CoumntA
- Most values (50% or more feels about right) are ***exactly zero***

In that case, two queries will be faster.  This is because each query can use the index to quickly home in on the section to be counted.  In the end only counting the relevant records.

The example I gave, however, scans the whole table every time.  Only once, but always the whole table.  This is worth it when you're counting most of the records.  In your case it looks liek you're counting most or all of them, and so this is probably a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(CoumntA < 0, 1, 0)) AS lowerThanZero,
SUM(IF(CoumntA > 0, 1, 0)) AS greaterThanZero
FROM
TableA
```

Is it clear what's happening? Ask, if you have any more questions.

A shorter form would be

```
SELECT
SUM(CoumntA < 0) AS lowerThanZero,
SUM(CoumntA > 0) AS greaterThanZero
FROM
TableA
```

This is possible, since in MySQL a true condition is equal 1, a false condition is equal 0

EDIT: okay, okay, sorry, don't know why I thought it's about MySQL here.

See the other answers about correct syntax.

Comment: Neither of these are SQL Server syntax. (Your approach is spot on though.)

Comment: @tombom - Change them to CASE WHEN, MySQL short cuts won't work on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this in one select statement.

The way I've done it before is like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnA < 0 THEN 1 END) AS LessThanZero, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnA > 0 THEN 1 END) AS GreaterThanZero
FROM dbo.TableA
```

This is the correct MS SQL syntax and I believe this is a very efficient way of doing it.

Don't forget you are not covering the case when `ColumnA = 0`!

Answer (score 1):

```
select '< 0' as filter, COUNT(0) as cnt from TableA where [condition 1]
union
select '> 0' as filter, COUNT(0) as cnt from TableA where [condition 2]
```

Be sure that condition 1 and condition 2 create a partition on the original set of records, otherwise same records could be counted in both groups.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, one way would be;

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CoumntA<0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CoumntA>0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM dbo.TableA
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5c09/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) filter( where CoumntA < 0) as column_a_lt0, 
       count(*) filter (where CoumntA  > 0) as column_a_gt_0
FROM dbo.TableA
```

The query above will solve your issue.

In PostgreSQL, "count(*) filter (where condition)" expressions are used to count the number of rows that satisfy a given condition.
On the other hand, an alternative answer that can be found in other resources, but that does **not** address your issue, is the "count(condition)" expression.

The "count(condition)" expression evaluates the condition for each row, mapping each row to a boolean value. Then, it counts the number of boolean values, that will be equal to the total number of rows.

This can be verified by means of the following query

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 0 AS c1, 0 AS c2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1
)
SELECT COUNT(c1 = 1) as count_condition, COUNT(c1 = 0 AND c2 = 0) as count_condition_conjunction,
count(*) filter (where c1=1) as count_filter, count (*) filter (where c1=0 and c2=0) as count_filter_conjunction
FROM data;
```

That will output 4, 4, 2, 1